# targeting specific UL when there are more than one of the same class?

Tags: jquery, html-lists, show-hide

I'm creating code that will place tabbed content on my pages. The code creates tabs that when clicked, show and hide content beneath them. the active tab alos becomes white, while the inactive ones turn grey.

The tabbing content works great, however, I need to be able to put more than one group of tabbed content on the same page.

When I have more than one group of tabs, when you click in either group, it is causing the content in both to be affected. The active white tab is cleared from both groups, and the content below each group is hidden.

I need the changes to occur to each group of tabs separately.

I have a fiddle linked here:

http://jsfiddle.net/4bsdt/

This is the function that I am having problems with:

```
$(".myTabz li").click(function() {
                taby = $(this);
        tabyHas = taby.hasClass('active');
        if (!tabyHas){
     //I WANT ONLY THE CURRENT GROUP OF TABS TO BE CLEARED OF THE ACTIVE CLASS
        $(".myTabz li").removeClass('active');
                    // NOT WORKING $(this).find('.myTabz li').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass("active");
    //I only want content in the current group of tabs to disappear and reappear
        $(".tabz_content").hide();
        var focused =  $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        $(focused).fadeIn();
        return false;
        }
```

You will see that I have two groups of tabs, one with 4 tabs and one with two. When you click either group, the content is cleared from the other one...

I know it must have to do with targeting the UL that the user is currently clicking inside, but I am unsure of how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to limit the scope of your selectors, like follows  **[see updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4bsdt/1/)**

```
        $(".myTabz li").click(function () {
           taby = $(this);
           tabyHas = taby.hasClass('active');
           if (!tabyHas) {

              //***This line gets container of the current clicked "li"***
              var cntnr = $(this).closest('.wrapper');

              //***this line restricts scope of selector to container only***
              $(".myTabz li", cntnr).removeClass('active');

              //$(this).find('.myTabz li').removeClass('active');

              $(this).addClass("active");

              //I only want content in the current group of tabs to disappear and reappear
              //***this restricts the selector to the container only***
              $(".tabz_content", cntnr).hide();

              var focused = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
              $(focused).fadeIn();
              return false;
           }
        });
```

Comment: Awesome. I knew it would look something like that. I'm still trying to get the hang of "scope". Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could put the tabs and the content for each group into one div and traverse the elements through that div via `$(this).parent().find(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Change the following:

- `$(".myTabz li").removeClass('active');` becomes **`$(this).closest(".myTabz").find("li").removeClass('active');`**
- `$(".tabz_content").hide();` becomes **`$(this).closest(".wrapper").find(".tabz_content").hide();`**

You need to target objects around the specific `li` you click on. [`$(this).closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) is the easiest way to find specific items in relation to the .myTabz li you've clicked on. It also allows you to go as many layers up as necessary, unlike `$(this).parent();`

[See the JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/RyqAD/)